# How to Capture Events of Flash Player Using Javascript

Tags: visual-studio, flash, externalinterface, smooth-streaming

I want to handle smooth streaming events on client side like video ended, paused...
But not using externalinterface is there any way?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/) it can help you (it's C#).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misundertood it. ExternalInterface you use to call a method on your web page (like javascript) from flash. But you don't write an actionscript class on Visual Studio, you can write a javascript and call it using the ExternalInterface.

You can find tutorials on the ExternalInterface here:
http://lightness.co.uk/external-interface-examples/

Comment: what I don't understand is where is the ExternalInterface file or where should I put or where should I create it and how to manipulate it?